# Jquery file validator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a jquery validator which look for file input with special attribute

`<input type="file" id="filelist" multiple MyFile  data-ext="ppdf,doc">`

Where MyFile is the special attribute. and I look for it in js using

```
$("input[MyFile]").each(function() {

 //staff used for checking 

});
```

everything works good untill now. the main problem is when there is 2 inputs in the same page.
I think this is caused by the variables in my code but I don't know how to deal with it.

My full code is here http://jsfiddle.net/Jz6KW/2/

Comment: Did you try to add a class to your input to specify which one to validate?

Comment: I think MyFile is enough. Btw I need the two inputs to be validated sperately